# How to remove xmonad and bluetile from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xmonad

How can I remove xmonad  and blue tile from ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a package, use `apt-get remove <packagename>`. This would leave the configuration files on your system, so if you reinstall later, the config files can be re-used.

To completely wipe the package and its configuration file, use `apt-get purge <packagename>.`

In your case the packages are calles "xmonad" and "bluetile".